# Tampermonkey waitForKeyElements on successive YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have a script that currently does away with those pesky "Continue watching?" prompts on YouTube, using Tampermonkey and waitForKeyElements.

However, it only seems to work if the prompt appears on the first YouTube video that I load (within the video, not between them). It doesn't seem to work for prompts on successive videos when I keep my autoplay going. When a prompt appears at the start of a new video, it doesn't seem to work at all. Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

I've heard this could be because YouTube replaces "history state" and doesn't actually reload/change pages when going from one video to the next (please let me know if I'm wrong on this). How could I cater the following script to modern YouTube autoplay/"page changes"?

Basically, how do I get the waitForKeyElements and function to fire every single time the prompt appears when I autoplay videos for an extended period of time (whether on the first video or another)?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     YouTube Yes SJ3
// @include  https://www.youtube.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements ("#confirm-button.style-scope.yt-confirm-dialog-renderer.style-blue-text.size-default:contains('Yes')", clicks);

    function clicks (jNode) {
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
        console.log('SJ3');
}
```

Comment: What if you add `waitForKeyElements ("#confirm-button.style-scope.yt-confirm-dialog-renderer.style-blue-text.size-default:contains('Yes')", clicks);` at the end of the `clicks()` function? Currently your script waits for the popup to appear once, then exits.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you're saying to also add that line under `console.log()`? Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/d7bvnwsy/3/

Comment: Yes. This way the script will always wait for popups to appear and will remove them accordingly

Comment: Thanks! I've been testing it the last few days and it works in the sense that it now removes all of the popups, even when advanced to another YouTube video. But right after successfully removing a popup when on an autoplayed video, it seems to want to fire infinitely, even affecting the performance of my PC. Is there any way to prevent this "infinite" firing? In other words, it seems like the script fires infinitely after closing the popup the second time or whenever I'm not on the first video - even after the popup has been successfully removed. Perhaps I should use another selector?

Comment: So I'm trying a different method now where I use setTimeout to delay the last waitForKeyElements by 30 seconds. It doesn't seem to work, though. Any ideas how to simply delay that next line of code so that this script doesn't fire indefinitely? Here's my newest code: https://jsfiddle.net/8da0fL5w/1/

Comment: Actually, I think I know why it wasn't working with setTimeout(). Is this more correct? https://jsfiddle.net/h3t5k0an/ Thanks again for everything. You've helped a lot the last few days.

Comment: It still only seems to fire once even when using the newest version of the script. No idea why, to be honest.